# Render partial (customized to specific item in collection) on click *EDIT* how to pass params?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

RoR dummy here so please go easy on me. I'm iterating over a collection of Utility objects and for each one, I want to have an "edit" link that when clicked, renders a partial that has specific edit information for that bill.

I want to render a partial and pass the u.id param to that partial so I can display utility-specific information. Keeping in mind that I'm not great at Rails, how do I accomplish this? The view I'm working on is a partial render_uts in users#show. Thanks!

**Edit** : I almost have it working. The partial is rendered on click. But I don't know how to pass u.id or any parameters to the partial.

show.html.erb

```
<% @utilities.each do |u| %>
     <%= link_to u.name, '/users/show', :remote => true %>
<% end  %>
```

_utilEdit.html.erb

```
<%= Utility name should go here? %>
```

At the end of the show method in my users controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js
end
```

And in show.js.erb:

```
$("#editUtil").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render 'utilEdit') %>');
```

($("#editUtil") is my placeholder.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand actually what you want
Suppose you want to edit utility since it's member route you can use `edit_utility_path(u)` 
Or you want to render partial in same UI you can passed as locals like `<%= render :partial=>"...",:locals=>{"utility_id"=>u.id} %>`,or you can pass object as option
Refer [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: I only want to render the partial when the link is clicked since it would take too much time loading otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your show.html.erb you should pass an utility id to show action:

```
<% @utilities.each do |u| %>
 <%= link_to u.name, utility_path(u), :remote => true %>
 <!-- or if you have some strange routes -->
 <%= link_to u.name, "/utilities/#{u.id}", :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

Then you should found utility in your show action

```
def show
  @utility = Utility.find(params[:id])
end
```

In your partial(_utilEdit.html.erb) you should wrote smth like this:

```
<%= utility.name %>
```

In show.js.erb you should pass @utility:

```
$("#editUtil").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'utilEdit', :locals => {:utility => @utility}) %>');
```

Read more about partials and variables: [Local variables in partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)